# What will be the query in case of date parameter?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a birthday date column of employees. I want to find out the employees whose birthday on this date.

I am passing a date to a query h to get employ whose birthday on this date.
But the problem is that date is given in DateTime formate and table birthday column also in DateTime formate.

eg, `2017-04-25 09:00:00`

I want results on basic of date only not on their time. For example:

In table date is given in birthday column

```
2017-04-25 09:00:00
2017-04-25 05:00:00
```

I am passing date  `2017-04-25 09:00:00` in JPA query then both date should return. The result should be on the basis of date only.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use date '2017-04-25' to compare ? or you want to compare it with month and date only '04-25' ? You will not get any records if you compare it with whole date.

Comment: @FahadAnjum: agree with you. Also can you update the exact database name, MySQL or PostgreSQL????

Comment: Who records an employee's time of birth?

Comment: Refrain from using words like urgent, immediate etc in S.O

Comment: @Strawberry actually my original problem was different. i it was difficult to explain  the actual Scenario . so i ask question in simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare @inputdate     datetime

```
select * from Emp_table where Cast(birthdaycol as date)= cast(@inputdate as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cast()` or `convert()`

```
where cast(birthday as date) = '2017-04-25'
```

For your parameter you can express this as

```
where cast(birthday as date) = cast(@parameter as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like below query:

```
    select * from your table where date(yourDateColumn)='2017-04-25'
```